# Is it possible to use nodejs express with any jquery library like datatables?

Tags: node.js, templating

I want to be able to use nodejs with jquery without having to execute an npm install as I want to use jquery strictly on the client side. I know this is not possible with the Jade templating engine as its syntax is completely different, but is it possible with some other templating engine? I would prefer not to have a bunch of HTML to haml just to make nodejs happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible to use jQuery or any other JavaScript client-side library with Jade. You'll need to figure out the syntax to include a JavaScript file and JavaScript code with whatever engine you use. With Jade you can use script() to include an external file (like the jQuery library) and then script to code your specific calls. Take a look at the Jade documentation here: https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme

Below is an example of a Jade file that (1) includes jQuery and then (2) updates an HTML element ("message") through jQuery:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.js')
  body
    h1= title
    p#container Welcome to #{title}
    p#message (to be filled in)
    script
      alert('hello world');
      $("#message").html("message set through jquery")
```

Comment: I would like to use the following "http://datatables.net/", would that be "compatible" with Jade?

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of Jade as a different language or something that is in any way incompatible with your existing HTML/JS stack - it's just a shorthand way to write HTML which allows you to inject server-side data as a byproduct.

For my personal stack I use express + jade on the server side and then angularjs, jquery and twitter bootstrap on the client side. I use require.js to manage all of my imports, and in my jade template I just have a single script() reference that points to the main.js file that has all of my require.js logic in it.

But, as far as express/jade go - the key is to make sure that you understand that it's not there to complicate your life, it's there to make your life easier. If you feel like it's confusing, switch to a different templating engine or simply have express serve up static html pages with nothing injected and set up AJAX services to get the server-side data you need.